# Cpanel - How to creat folder for all user

Tags: cpanel

I want to creat a folder for all user connect and include if use php command.
Example:

```
/folder/file.php
```

I can use php command to include in php file

My file: /home/user/public_html/test.php
PHP Code:

```
include('/folder/file.php');
```

Please help me

I try with root permission and chmod 0777 for all folder and file but can not include

Comment: `/folder` is it folder in root directory?

Answer (score 0):

try checking the apache logs

> tail -f  /etc/httpd/logs/error_log

While you are loading the page test.php in browser. See what you gets.

Also where is the file test.php is located .